# ¿Como encriptar archivo de conexión Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, base-de-datos

Necesito encontrar la forma de encriptar y desencriptar de una manera segura y confiable el contenido del archivo de conexión que tiene los datos de la DB como el host, port, user y password. Terminé el desarrollo de una app de escritorio en java y nunca pensé que algo que parecía simple se me complicara tanto.

De antemano muchas gracias a cualquier consejo o experiencia que me pueda servir, estoy abierto a la posibilidad de manejar de una manera distinta la conexión si es necesario.